# Probability of two independent dice rolls

Tags: probability

> When two unbiased dice are rolled one by one, what is the probability that either the first is $2$ or the sum of the two is less than $5$?

My Reasoning:

$$P(A) = P(\text{first one is}\; 2) = \frac{1}{6}$$

$$P(B) = P(\text{sum is less than}\; 5) = \frac{6}{36} = \frac{1}{6}$$

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B) = \frac{11}{26}$$

What I'm doing wrong? The book says the right solution is  $\frac{5}{18}$.

Comment: What is $P(A \cap B)$? List the rolls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you didn't calculate well $P(A\cap B)$, because there are only 2 options:  (2,1) and (2,2). So
$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{2}{36}=\frac{5}{18}$$